# How do I show $(a^2 - b^2 + c^2 - d^2)^2 +2 (ab - bc + dc +ad)^2 = (a^ 2+b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2 - 2(ab - ad + bc + dc)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there are way to prove the following expression directly without expanding and collecting terms? i.e transform the LHS into the RHS?

$$(a^2 - b^2  + c^2 - d^2)^2 +2 (ab - bc + dc +ad)^2 \\\qquad= (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2 - 2(ab - ad + bc + dc)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the terms. It suffices to show that 
$$2[(ab-bc+dc+ad)^2+(ab-ad+bc+dc)^2]=(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2-(a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2)^2.$$
For the RHS, we have 
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2-(a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2)^2=(2a^2+2c^2)(2b^2+2d^2)=4(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2).$$
For the LHS, we can observe that 
\begin{align*}
&(ab-bc+dc+ad)^2+(ab-ad+bc+dc)^2 \\
=\ &[(ab+dc)+(ad-bc)]^2+[(ab+dc)-(ad-bc)^2] \\
=\ &2[(ab+dc)^2+(ad-bc)^2]=\cdots. 
\end{align*}
I believe you can complete the remaining proof.

Answer (score 0):

$((a^2+c^2)+(b^2+d^2))^2-((a^2+c^2)-(b^2+d^2))^2$

$=(2(a^+c^2)2(b^2+d^2))$

$=4(a^+c^2)(b^2+d^2)$

$=4((ab)^2+(bc)^2+(cd)^2+(da)^2)$

And, 
$2(ab+dc+(ad-bc))^2+2(ab+dc-(ad-bc))^2$

$=4((ab+dc)^2+(ad-bc)^2)$

$=4((ab)^2+(bc)^2+(cd)^2+(da)^2)$

So,

$(a^2 - b^2 + c^2 - d^2)^2 - (a^ 2+b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2$

$=2(ab - ad + bc + dc) + 2 (ab - bc + dc +ad)^2 $

$\Rightarrow 
(a^2 - b^2 + c^2 - d^2)^2 +2 (ab - bc + dc +ad)^2 $

$= (a^ 2+b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^2 - 2(ab - ad + bc + dc) $